# How can I use jest-specific-snapshot with ava?

Tags: ava

I'm migrating my tests from jest to ava; in my jest setup, I used jest-specific-snapshot to have one snapshot file per testcase (I sometimes adjust my snapshots manually, and it's easier on my editor if not everything lives in one large file). Can jest-specific-snapshot be used with ava (and if so, how), or can something similar be achieved in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest-specific-snapshot` does not work with AVA. You can't control where individual snapshots are written, either. But you can't adjust snapshots manually either, so you may want to revisit your use case.